# using php symfony framework

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony1

One of my projects (PHP) I'm thinking of using symfony. I'm pretty new to php , but has a rails experience over 3 years. My questions are

The project I'm thinking is having some basic CURD operations with MySQL and some AJAX. and heavy reporting

1 - Is 'symfony' is a dependable framework (with the scalability, AJAX support etc..) , if not what are the advised frameworks

2- if i go with 'symfony' is there any special server requirements needs to be met or can I use any hosting provider who supports PHP5 and MySQL

thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 1):

Ad. 1: Yeah, Symfony 1.4 is stable and quite well designed framework. AJAX requestes shouldn't cause any problems.

Ad. 2: PHP 5.2.4 or newer, but not 5.2.9 is required and APC or similar is heavly recommended. You can run that [`check_configuration.php`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/data/bin/check_configuration.php) script to check whether or not your server is configured propertly for Symfony app.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Crozin:
for #2, if you are running on a shared host, make sure your space is secured from other hosts running in the same environment [link](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/SharedHostingNotSecure) and ensure the mod_rewrite required for the pretty urls works for you host.